# Tempered representations and unramified principal series

Tags: rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups, unitary-representations, buildings, tempered-distributions

For $V$ a tempered representation of connected reductive group over a local field of characteristic zero. I want to show that for an Iwahori subgroup $B$, the set of fixed points  $V^B\neq 0$, thereby establishing $V$ a sub-quotient of unramified principal series by a theorem of $Casselman$ I believe. However I can't seem to get a hold of this, and in the literature, I can't seem to find any proof of the implication that $$V \text{ tempered}\implies V^B\neq 0.$$
Perhaps there is another way to think about this, in the sense that $V$ tempered implies tautologically that $V$ is unramified, but I don't know.
Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: This is super, super false. Most tempered representations don't have an Iwahori-fixed vector. Any supercuspidal representation gives a counterexample!

Comment: Here's a more convincing example, since supercuspidals aren't very explicit. Take $G=SL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$, with $B=UT \subset G$ the usual Borel, so $T={\mathbf{Q}_p}^\times$. Let $\chi$ be some smooth character of ${\mathbf{Q}_p}^\times$ which sends $p$ to $1$ (or to any complex number of modulus $1$...) and is nontrivial on the subgroup $1+p\mathbf{Z}_p$. Then the normalized parabolic induction $i_{B}^{G}(\chi)$ is tempered and has no Iwahori-fixed vector.

Comment: Thanks, as it appears I misunderstood greatly these concepts.